# Making a menu item appear when a certain view is displayed rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, view

Windows 8.1
Rails 4.1
Ruby 2.0

I have the menus for my application defined in views/layout, and one of those is the header where I have the menu items. There are some additional partials rendered form _header.html.erb as well.

I would like to have an additional menu appear ONLY when I render views/pages/index. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look in Javascript. Have you tried listening for the specific body class of that page? Each body gets a dynamically generated attribute of class="controller action". If you listen for body.controller.action, you'll have the event that can trigger you to show (or hide) your menu item.

Pseudo code might look like:

```
I want a new menu to appear for controller1, action1

when any action fires in any controller
    if the class of the body element has both class "controller1" and class "action1" 
        menu.show()
    else
        menu.hide()
```